# Cannot find interface declaration for 'Object', superclass of 'Track'; did you mean 'NSObject'?

Tags: macos, swift2, cocoapods, realm

[image]

I am integrating RealmSwift framework to my OS X project.

```
import RealmSwift 
public class Track: Object {
    // class members and functions
}
```

I changed Track class to extend Object instead of NSObject, I am getting this error in ProjectName-Swift.h

```
@interface Track : Object
```

I am using CocoaPods for dependency management. I did googling for this issue but didn't get much.

Added RealmSwift dependency like this

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
```

Comment: Show is the interface for class Object. If you have one. If not, that would explain it.

Comment: @gnasher729 not following you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you created [an issue for that on the realm-cocoa repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2664) as well, here a cross-post of the summary from that:

Generally the automatically generated Objective-C compatibility header shouldn't cause issues when integrating with CocoaPods.

As a workaround, you could just disable for now the generation by setting the build setting `SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER` to `NO`.

[image: SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER]

Please note, that we discourage from using RealmSwift in mixed setups, where Objective-C is used alongside to Swift to access the model.

If your model classes should be among the classes, which are included in the bridging header, or if there are any other classes, which (transitively) depend on them, then you can't really use Realm Swift in this setup.

You would need to replace the entry in your Podfile by `pod "Realm"`, run `pod install` again and inherit from `RLMObject` instead. Further steps may be needed depending on if you have started already implementing application / model logic on base of the Realm Swift APIs, as Realm Objective-C APIs don't bring the same functional flavor.

Comment: Thanks, I changed to use Realm and using RLMObject and RLMArray. But now constant getting this error. 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray objectClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000427960'

Comment: Do you have a stack trace which indicates where this error indicates from?